# What is the differences between dask.bag / dask.delayed for loop, choose better way for python paralell jobs in dask

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask

Env info:

```
Python==3.7
Win7 i5-2310:2-cores-4-threads 4GB-memory
```

Dask Ini:

```
from dask.distributed import Client

Client()

# Client Scheduler: tcp://127.0.0.1:50723 Dashboard:
# http://127.0.0.1:8787/status Cluster Workers: 4 Cores: 4 Memory: 4.20 GB
```

First One:
Delayed Function with For-loop:

```
@dask.delayed
def teststr(x,y):
    return x+y


rt=[]
for i in range(1000):
    rt.append(teststr(str(i),str(i+1)) )
rt = dask.compute(*rt)
```

It shows `Wall time: 3.23 s`

Second One:
List Based Bag with map function:

```
import dask.bag as db

b=db.from_sequence([(str(i),str(i+1)) for i in range(1000)])

def teststr2(x,y):
    return x+y

%%time
rt2=b.map(lambda x:teststr2(x[0],x[1])).compute()
```

It shows `Wall time: 899 ms`

The forloop one takes much more time than the bag one ,and it costs disk IO a lot(maybe virtual-mem).

I haven't check what would happen if I change the dask.client configure(thread vs process) ,the different tasks(Integer function vs string funcion vs function without GIL vs database IO vs Disk IO) or larger object(working with large DataFrame or Numpy while doing some data analyse job. ).

How to  choose better way for python paralell jobs in dask. Though I get same output, sometime it takes too much time computing. There must be some rules help me.

I hope it might be a cheat-sheets which tell me the best way to organise my code based on System-Env, kinds of the task or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major difference between the two options is the number of tasks. You can do `len(thing.dask)` to get a quick look at the graph needed to compute a given dask object, delayed or bag.

```
>>> rt2=b.map(lambda x:teststr2(x[0],x[1]))
>>> len(rt2.dask)
200

>>> rt=[]
>>> for i in range(1000):
...     rt.append(teststr(str(i),str(i+1)) )
>>> sum(len(t.dask) for t in rt)
1000
```

So the number of tasks in the bag is five times fewer, and this is because bag does its computations in batches on the input (also called partitions). Since the compute function that you are requesting happens so quickly, the total time is totally dominated by the per-task overhead and by the time taken to send the graph of tasks to the scheduler.

Comment: I checked the `b.npartitions=100` which is the default value. So what is the npartitions? Does it means for the 1000 jobs, run 100 batches, each of them contain 10 jobs? So Why not 4 jobs each since we have a 4 threads cores CPU?

Comment: Simply: this is what bag does for you. Yes, each partition is a collection of items, which when you run `map` will translate into a set of function calls (I do not call them "jobs"). Ideally, the partition size is picked so that each task has enough to do to be small compared to the overhead, and not so big that the partition itself causes memory pressure.